# cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'required'. No child element is expected at this point

Tags: required, tld

[image]

When I am enabling the required elements in dictionary.tld I am getting the error

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'required'. No child element is expected at this point.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Add code instead of image

Comment: thank you,I change the position,is not get wrong.